# Message not displaying on toggle

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display error msg in my code, but it isn't working, i tried with `style.display` and .visbility.

Both are giving me this error
index.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
at HTMLButtonElement.refresh (index.js:16)

What am I doing wrong?

```js
const mailBtn = document.querySelector('.email-btn');
const mailInput = document.querySelector('.email-input').value;
const mailBox = document.querySelector('.email-input');
let errMsg =  document.querySelector('.red');
const refresh = () => {
    if(mailInput.length < 5) {
        mailBox.classList.add('error')
        mailInput = `Can't be blank`;
        errMsg.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        location.reload();

    }
}

mailBtn.addEventListener('click', refresh);
```

Comment: You can't reassign the value of a [constant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). If reassigning the value to the variable would make sense (which it doesn't in our case as @volper pointed out), you'd have to use `let` instead of `const`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because `.value` returns a string, which is copied by value and not returned by reference, so changing it is no good. Instead use the reference to the element:

```js
mailBox.value = "Can't be blank";
```

instead of

```js
mailInput = `Can't be blank`;
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Could you have a look please https://jsfiddle.net/tgyvqw0z/ , all the time it thinks that the input `length` is 0, even when I type input.  Why is this happening?

Comment: As I said, `.value` will return a copy, so `mailInput` will not change on click. Delete the `mailInput` variable and use `mailBox.value.length < 2` instead.